# is there a way to change the value of main.dart

Tags: flutter

What i am trying to achieve is that when my app runs for the first time list of schools are shown and when i select one school i am redirected to login page. the problem here is when i select one school i get one key form there and i want to pass that key inside my my_app.dart which is used in main.dart without restarting the whole app. I am able to change the value of key but app keeps restarting need some guidance .

This is my code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () => KhaltiScope(
        publicKey: globalCtrl.khaltiPubKey.value,
        builder: (context, navKey) {
          return GetMaterialApp(
            translations: LanguageTranslate(),
            locale: Get.deviceLocale,
            smartManagement: SmartManagement.full,
            initialBinding: Binder(),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Merovidya Student',
            navigatorKey: navKey,
            fallbackLocale: const Locale("en", "US"),
            theme: ThemeData(
              primaryColor: primaryColor1,
              visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: scaffoldBackgroundColor,
              brightness: Brightness.light,
            ),
            getPages: MeroRoutes.routes,
            supportedLocales: const [
              Locale('en', 'US'),
              Locale('ne', 'NP'),
            ],
            localizationsDelegates: const [
              KhaltiLocalizations.delegate,
            ],
            home: const SplashScreen(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the simple function i made in my globalcontroller to change public key this is just test function

```
changePublicKey() {
    logger.i("This is public key", khaltiPubKey.value);
    khaltiPubKey.value = Keys.khalthiPublicKey;
    logger.i("This is public key1", khaltiPubKey.value);
  }
```

and i have initialized globalController in my main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    //DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    // DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    // DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
  ]);
  Binder();
  await Preferences().init();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  Get.put(GlobalController(), permanent: true);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Need some guidance here Thanks.

Comment: is there a way to change the main.dart value with or without getx?

Comment: if you put Obx outside the GetMaterialApp it will always rebuild everytime the value changes and thats why it keeps reloading

Comment: so is there any other way to do it i am really stuck here.